# Dropdownlist throwing too few args error when including a where statement in Yii2

Tags: drop-down-menu, yii2

I am trying to use a dropdownlist in an active form which includes some where statements.  I have tried so many variaions and im stumped.
Here is the code block

```
echo $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList(
                ArrayHelper::map(Products::find()
                    ->where('pid','43')
                    ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product_name', 'window'],
                [
                    'prompt' => 'Operating System',
                ])));
```

I am not sure how to go about this.

Comment: You're clearly doing to many things at once - try split this into two three steps: query products, using `ArrayHelper::map()` on result, and then generating field. Or at least use some indentation to see what is actual happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Yii2 ArrayHelper map()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-helpers-basearrayhelper#map()-detail)

```
echo $form->field($model, 'pid')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Products::find()
                ->where(['pid' => '43'])
                ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'product_name', 'window'])->all(), 'your_id', 'your_name'), 
            [
                'prompt' => 'Operating System',
            ]);
```